# Ratio between two raster layers

Tags: qgis, python

I have to find the ratio between the first raster layer in folder R:\prova\VH and the first raster layer in folder R:\prova\VV, then I have to repeat the operation for the second two layers belonging to the two folders and so on.

The layers are sorted alphabetically and have the same dimension and CRS.

Each folder contains the same number of raster files.

I wrote this script in Python for QGIS 2.18 but it doesn't sort any result.

```
import os, os.path
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

raster1_filepath = "R:\\prova\\VH"
raster2_filepath = "R:\\prova\\VV"

outputDir = "R:\\prova\\Out"

for i in os.listdir(raster1_filepath):

    layercount1 = os.path.join(raster1_filepath, i)  
    layercount2 = os.path.join(raster2_filepath, i)  

    raster_layer1 = QgsRasterLayer(layercount1, 'raster')
    raster_layer2 = QgsRasterLayer(layercount2, 'raster')

    entries = []
    # Define numerator
    ras1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras1.ref = 'raster_layer1@1'
    ras1.raster = raster_layer1
    ras1.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras1 )

    # Define denominator
    ras2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras2.ref = 'raster_layer2@1'
    ras2.raster = raster_layer2
    ras2.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( ras2 )

    # Process calculation with input extent and resolution
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( 'raster_layer1@1 / raster_layer2@1', \
    outputDir, \
    'GTiff', \
    raster_layer2.extent(), \
    raster_layer2.width(), \
    raster_layer2.height(), 
    entries )
    calc.processCalculation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
import os
import os.path
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#rasterVH_filepath = "R:\\prova\\VH"
#rasterVV_filepath = "R:\\prova\\VV"
#outpath = "R:\\prova\\out"
#
rasterVH_filepath = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/divisione/VH"
rasterVV_filepath = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/divisione/VV"
outpath = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/divisione/out"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# liste
listaVH = sorted([VH for VH in os.listdir(rasterVH_filepath) if VH.endswith(".tif")])
listaVV = sorted([VV for VV in os.listdir(rasterVV_filepath) if VV.endswith(".tif")])

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# number of files
number_files = len(listaVH)
index = range(0, number_files)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# join of folder anf file VH
AlistaVH = []

for filVH in listaVH:
    layercountVH = os.path.join(rasterVH_filepath, filVH)
    AlistaVH.append(layercountVH)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# join of folder anf file VV
AlistaVV = []

for filVV in listaVV:
    layercountVV = os.path.join(rasterVV_filepath, filVV)
    AlistaVV.append(layercountVV)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
entries = []

for i in index:

    checknameVH = listaVH[i]
    checknameVV = listaVV[i]

    if checknameVH[:-11] == checknameVV[:-11]:
        entries = []

        nOut =listaVH[i]
        outFile = outpath + "/" + nOut[:-11] + "ratio_clip.tif"

        # Define band1
        raster_layerVH = QgsRasterLayer(AlistaVH[i], "raster")
        rasVH = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        rasVH.ref = "raster_layerVH@1"
        rasVH.raster = raster_layerVH
        rasVH.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append( rasVH )

        # Define band2
        raster_layerVV = QgsRasterLayer(AlistaVV[i], "raster")
        rasVV = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        rasVV.ref = "raster_layerVV@1"
        rasVV.raster = raster_layerVV
        rasVV.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append( rasVV )

        # Process calculation with input extent and resolution
        calc = QgsRasterCalculator("raster_layerVH@1 / raster_layerVV@1", \
        outFile, \
        "GTiff", \
        raster_layerVH.extent(), \
        raster_layerVH.width(), \
        raster_layerVH.height(), \
        entries)
        calc.processCalculation()

    else:
        print("check the name or the order of your files!!!!!")
    #   #iface.addRasterLayer(calc, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fileOutClip))[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried running this (only in my head) :-)

I think the problem might be that you're passing a directory name - not a unique file name - to the [QgsRasterCalculator()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterCalculator.html#a2d6223859ab758438290edc674ad0362) call

```
calc = QgsRasterCalculator( 'raster_layer1@1 / raster_layer2@1', \
    outputDir, \  # <--- this line
    'GTiff', \
    raster_layer2.extent(), \
    raster_layer2.width(), \
    raster_layer2.height(), 
    entries )
calc.processCalculation()
```

that should probably be a full file name, e.g.

```
os.path.join(outputDir, something),
```

Also, you're not checking for valid file extensions, so if your directory contains non-raster files (e.g. .pngw for georeferenced PNGs) that might cause problems too.

Comment: Hi steven. I tried using outFile = layercount1[:-6] + "ratio.tif" instead of output Dir, but no changes